# iOS Shake Gesture - Double Shake

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-motion, shake

I got the normal shake gesture implemented as follows:

```
 import CoreMotion

 override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
      if motion == .motionShake {'
         print ("SHAKE GESTURE DETECTED")
      }
 }
```

I notice this is somewhat of a nuisance sometimes, for example, if you put the device down suddenly, above code invokes.

Is there such a thing as "Double Shake", shake twice to invoke?

Answer (score 1):

There is not an official "Double Shake" gesture, but you can achieve this by using a simple counter variable:

```
var shakeCount = 0
override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
        shakeCount += 1
        if shakeCount == 2 {
            shakeCount = 0
            print ("SHAKE GESTURE DETECTED")
        }
    }
}
```

I would also suggest adding an **NSTimer** after the first shake that will reset the shakeCount after a certain amount of time.